# 403 Forbidden error when making an ajax Post request

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xmlhttprequest

My code is working fine on localhost(wamp server) but upon moving it to a shared hosting, I get error 403 (forbidden).
I tried this first:

```
    $.post('login.php?login', { user_email: user_email, user_password: user_password, user_remember: user_remember }, function(data)
    {
     // Some code here
    }
```

Then I tried this:

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "login.php?login";
var params = "user_email="+user_email+"&user_password="+user_password+"&user_remember="+user_remember;
http.open("POST", url, true);

http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

http.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        // Some code here
    }
}
http.send(params);
```

But I still get this error:

> POST http://domain_name/login.php?login 403 (Forbidden)

Any idea whats wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a few possibilities here.

1. A 403 on shared hosting USUALLY means that there's a permissions issue on the file you're trying to contact. Basically, the web server is saying, "No, I'm not going to allow you to access or run login.php." You might want to double-check the owner and permissions of that file, in case it was uploaded incorrectly somehow.
2. There's also a slim chance that you might have an .htaccess file that is set up to respond with a 403 error code under certain circumstances, so if you have one of those, look for anything that talks about allow/deny/grant, then try commenting out those lines (temporarily, just to see if it's the cause) and try to access login.php again.
3. Next possibility is that your login.php itself is written to respond with a 403 error code under certain circumstances. For example, maybe if you don't send the appropriate data to it or if it can't validate your login for some reason, maybe it responds with a 403 HTTP status code. In that scenario, I'd double-check to make sure that the data being sent to the login.php is valid and that login.php is set up correctly on the shared server (e.g. check database access, etc)
4. Final possibility is that your originating file is not on the same domain as your login.php. In other words, you're on http://domainA.com/page.html and making an AJAX call to http://domainB.com/login.php. This is referred to as a cross-domain call, and can also result in a 403 because cross-domain calls are forbidden for security reasons unless you take steps to enable them (you usually have to be in control of both sides to take those steps). So if that's how you're executing the AJAX call, try copying the originating file (page.html) to domainB.com where login.php is, and try it from there.

Comment: an addon to your list. 
I got into this problem, by sending and http request, but it always returned a 403.
Then I noticed that they have a csrf token in the form i was trying to replicate. 
To solve it I submitted the form, after inputting the data using js.